# When I filter by address I get this error: Syntax error: Missing operand after ' ' operator

Tags: c#

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dataGridViewShowPeople.DataSource;
bs.Filter = " Convert(ID, 'System.String') like '" + textBoxId.Text + "%' AND  Convert(lastName, 'System.String') like '%" + textBoxLastName.Text + "%' AND Convert(firstName, 'System.String') like '" + textBoxFirstName.Text + "%' AND Convert(address, 'System.String') like '" + textBoxAddress.Text + "%'";             
dataGridViewShowPeople.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: Let me guess. There is a single quote in the text of one or more of your textboxes ?

Comment: Convert(address, 'System.String') like '" + textBoxAddress.Text.Replace(@"'", "''") + "%'"

Comment: Let me ask another question. What datatype are 'lastName' 'firstName' and 'address'? Do you really need that ugly syntax? If the are already strings there is no need to apply the CONVERT function.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a single quote in one or more of your textboxes. This could break the string concatenation logic and confuse the code that tries to apply the Filter property.
You need to call the `string.Replace` method to double every quotation char inside the textboxes values as explained in MSDN for the [DataColumn.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

> User-defined values may be used within expressions to be compared with
>   column values. String values should be enclosed within single
>   quotation marks **(and each single quotation character in a string value
>   has to be escaped by prepending it with another single quotation
>   character)**. .....

However I find dubious the call to the CONVERT function, at least for the fields `firstName`, `lastName` and `address`. It is very likely that they are already strings on the db side, so there is no need to call the CONVERT function

```
string ID = textBoxId.Text.Replace("'", "''");
string last = textBoxLastName.Text.Replace("'","''");
string first = textBoxFirstName.Text.Replace("'", "''");
string address = textBoxAddress.Text.Replace("'", "''");
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dataGridViewShowPeople.DataSource;
bs.Filter = string.Format("Convert(ID, 'System.String') like '{0}%' AND " + 
                          "lastName like '%{1}%' AND firstName like '{2}%' AND " + 
                          "address like '{2}%'", ID, last, first, address);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bs.Filter = " Convert(ID, 'System.String') like '%" + textBoxId.Text + "%' AND  Convert(lastName, 'System.String') like '%" + textBoxLastName.Text + "%' AND Convert(firstName, 'System.String') like '%" + textBoxFirstName.Text + "%' AND Convert(address, 'System.String') like '%" + textBoxAddress.Text + "%'";
```

you missed `%` in some like places

Comment: no it's works ok whithout % the problem at the last "address"